# Angular 4 cookie based auth

Tags: angular, http, cookies

I have a cookie based authentification system in my app and after auth I'm being able to call my API successfully using `this._http.get(this.actionUrl, { withCredentials: true })`

But my problem is that I would also want to control the access to my components or route but I have no idea how I could achieve this.

Thank in advance

Answer (score 4, accepted):

What you are looking for are [**`Angular Guards`**](https://angular.io/guide/router#milestone-5-route-guards)

There are four different guard types we can use to protect our routes:

CanActivate - Decides if a route can be activated
CanActivateChild - Decides if children routes of a route can be activated
CanDeactivate - Decides if a route can be deactivated
CanLoad - Decides if a module can be loaded lazily

A Simple [canActivate](https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/AngularConcepts/blob/master/src/app/guards/auth.guard.ts) and [canDeactivate guard](https://github.com/rahulrsingh09/AngularConcepts/blob/master/src/app/guards/deactivate.guard.ts)

Live Example - https://rahulrsingh09.github.io/AngularConcepts/guard

Comment: Thanks, that's exactly what I was looking for, but it solve half the problem. In fact I know how I can restrain the access to my components but still I would like to know how I can access to my cookie and verify that it still exist and it didn't expire ?!

Comment: For that you might need a service or resolvers router resolvers check